# Simulate change does not work for formik's select elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, formik

I am trying to test some of the formik's select elements, and Simulate change does not work.

whereas the same simulate change works fine for formik's input elements.

**Component:**

```
 <Field
                      type="text"
                      name={'clientsData.language1_id'}
                      className={this.props.classes.textField}
                      label="Primary Language"
                      select
                      margin="normal"
                      variant="outlined"
                      component={TextField}
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true
                      }}>
                      }}>
                      {this.props.languages.map(val => (
                        <MenuItem key={val.id} value={val.id}>
                          {val.value}
                        </MenuItem>
                      ))}
                    </Field>
```

**Mount Wrapper:**

```
wrapper = mount(
      <Router history={hist}>
        <ClientsContacts
          clientsData={clientsData}
          languages={languages}
          gender={gender}
          race={race}
          genders_identified={genderIdentified}
          actions={{ getDictionaryApiCall: mockGetDictionaryApiCall, getListApiCall: mockGetListApiCall }}
        />
      </Router>
    )
```

**Simulate change and some console logs for better understanding:**

```
console.log(
      wrapper
        // .find('Select')
        .find('input')
        .at(6)
        .debug()
    )

    wrapper
      .find('input')
      .at(6)
      .simulate('change', { target: { value: '122344556644', name: 'clientsData.language1_id' } })

    console.log(
      wrapper
        .find('input')
        .at(6)
        .props()
    )
```

**Screenshot of console.log:**

[image: Screen Shot 2019-05-29 at 9 59 59 AM]

Above screenshot of console log shows value is not changed even after the simulate change.

Answer (score 1):

I Was able to fix it by using directly props.onChange

```
wrapper
      .find('SelectInput')
      .at(0)
      .props()
      .onChange({ target: { id: 1, value: 'American Sign Language', name: 'clientsData.language1_id' } })
    wrapper.update()
```